# Using Integral Test to show a series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> How do I show this series:
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{e^k}$$
>
> converges by using the Integral test?

---

So, first I have to show that it meets the conditions of the integral test:

1. must be positive
2. must be continuous
3. must be decreasing

Then, what do I do?

Comment: Examine the improper intagral $\int_1^{\infty} x\exp(-x)dx$

Comment: You can replace the series with an integral over x from 1 to infinity and evaluate the convergence of the integral

Comment: I'm confused, the series has to be continuous? Though, I get that the corresponding integral function $\frac x{e^x}$ should be continuous.

Comment: After I've taken the integral, what am I looking for to determine if it is convergent? Just that it equals a number?

Comment: If the integral is finite  then the series must converge because the values are less than or equal to that of the integral.

Comment: @LaSpana101: Yes! that's right. You may use the intgral by parts way to solve the integral.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $f(x)=x\exp(-x)$ is decreasing in $[1,+\infty)$. Therefore for any $k\geq 2$
$$0<\frac{k}{e^k}\leq \int_{k-1}^k x\exp(-x) dx$$
which implies that for $n\geq 1$,
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{e^k}\leq \frac{1}{e} +\int_1^n x\exp(-x) dx\leq \frac{1}{e} +\int_1^{+\infty} x\exp(-x) dx\\= \frac{1}{e}+[-(1+x)\exp(-x)]_1^{+\infty}=\frac{3}{e}.$$
Therefore the increasing sequence (the terms are positive) of the partial sums $S_n$ is bounded above by $\frac{3}{e}$. It follows that it has a finite limit $S$ (i.e the series is convergent to $S$).

P.S. It can be seen that $S=\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}<\frac{3}{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum ke^{-k}\; $ and $\; \int^{+\infty}xe^{-x}dx$ have same nature.

As the exponential is faster,

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^2.xe^{-x}=0$$

$\implies x^2.xe^{-x}\leq 1$ for large $x$.

$$\implies xe^{-x}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$\implies \int^{+\infty}xe^{-x}dx$$ converges by comparison test.

$$\implies \sum ke^{-k} $$ converges.